How to manage light/dark theme specific background color for `TabBar` widget displayed in `Slivers` in Flutter?
Trying to change background color of TabBar with theme change from light/dark. Found a way to manage indicatorColor, labelColor, unselectedLabelColor using TabBarTheme but there is no way for TabBar. Found TabBar will make use of PrimaryColor but that is also not helping even if having distinct primaryColor for both theme.  Is it because TabBar is inside Slivers.
DarkTheme
tabBarTheme: const TabBarTheme(
    labelColor: colorOffWhite,
    indicatorColor: colorBlackBg,
    unselectedLabelColor: disabledTextColor,
  ),

Light Theme
tabBarTheme: const TabBarTheme(
    labelColor: colorBlackBg,
    indicatorColor: colorBlackBg,
    unselectedLabelColor: disabledTextColor,
  ),


you can wrap TabBar Widget with Material widget and give it property color
Like this
Material(
  color: Colors.cyan[200],
  child: const TabBar(
    tabs: [
      Tab(
      text: "Tab 1",
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.timer,
          ),
         ),
         Tab(
           text: "Tab 2",
           icon: Icon(
             Icons.watch_outlined,
         ),
       ),
     ],
   ),
 ),


Yes this way we can do it. I need to manage it with Theme being managed from MaterialApp. Hence can't do this with this way or condition based.
